# I try to implement multithreading in Lua Api through coroutines using lua_sethook

Tags: c, lua

everyone. please help me. I try to implement multithreading in Lua Api through coroutines using lua_sethook.

here's the code

```
void LUAHook(lua_State* L, lua_Debug* ar) {
    lua_yield(L, 0);
};
 const char* LUA = R"(
function foo()
for i = 1, 4 do
print(" func foo \n")
end end

function main()
for i = 1, 3 do
print(" func main "..i.."\n")
if j == nil
then
 foo1()
j=1
end
end  end
)";
int foo1(lua_State* L) {
    lua_State* L1 = lua_newthread(L); 
    lua_sethook(L, LUAHook, LUA_MASKLINE, 1);
    lua_getglobal(L1, "foo");
    lua_sethook(L1, LUAHook, LUA_MASKLINE, 1);
    lua_resume(L1, L, 0);


return  0;
};
int main() {
    lua_State* L = luaL_newstate(); luaL_openlibs(L);
    lua_register(L, "foo1", foo1);
    luaL_dostring(L, LUA);
    int ret;
    lua_getglobal(L, "main");// функция lua возобновляется с последней 
    //  прерванной позиции.
    ret = lua_resume(L, NULL, 0);


    return 0;
};
```

you need to display the following in the console

func main 1
 func foo 
 func main 2
 func foo 
 func main 3
 func foo`enter code here`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).